# Compilation of firefox extension with xulrunner-sdk-9.0.1

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a FF toolbar working in all previous versions. I've compiled it with xulrunner-sdk-9.0.1 and created new xpi. Now on attempt to install the toolbar (dragging xpi onto browser) I'm getting a following error:

> ToolbarName could not be installed because it is not compatible with Firefox 9.0.1

Can somebody tell what's special with Firefox 9.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that the extension is not marked as compatible with Firefox 9.0.1, it is really only about extension metadata. Typically the `install.rdf` file of your extension will contain something like this:

```xml
<em:targetApplication>
  <Description>
    <!-- firefox -->
    <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
    <em:minVersion>9.0</em:minVersion>
    <em:maxVersion>9.0.*</em:maxVersion>
  </Description>
</em:targetApplication>
```

In your case it seems that `maxVersion` is some smaller value - update it and try again.